# Did proponents of classical and statistical thermodynamics get along well with each other?

Tags: physics, thermodynamics

Proponents of classical thermodynamics believed the subject matter to be continuous, while the statistical thermodynamics proponents' subject matter was made up of atoms and variations of collectives of them.

Were they in those days (19th century) each other's rival, or did they get along fine?

Comment: The atomistic hypothesis of matter by Dalton was known to all of them, but the theory of "classical thermodynamics" simply chose to ignore it. OTOH, Maxwell, Boltzmann and Gibbs simply chose a mechanistic view of matter and sought explanations of heat, work, energy, equilibrium with it.

Comment: @DanielC So they ignored each other? Or the classicals the probabiliticals at least. The other way round too?